# Is it possible to integrate LUIS with an Azure Calling Bot that accepts calls via Skype?

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service, skype-bots

I am working on a Chatbot in Azure and the whole conversation flow is based around the intent returned by LUIS. I recently tried deploying this bot to the Skype Channel because I want to be able to call the bot and interact using voice.

But although the chat feature works fine over Skype, I found that in order to enable skype calls we need to use a separate module called *botbuilder-calling* *(instead of botbuilder)* and this one doesn't support creating a recognizer to integrate with LUIS.

So my question is *how can I integrate my Azure Calling bot with LUIS?*

*I was under the impression that this is as simple as just deploying my existing chatbot to a voice enabled channel. Is this not the case?*

Comment: Were you looking to do this with botbuilder v3 or v4?

Comment: Hi Zeryth, my code is currently on botbuilder v3. But I am open to use any version.

Comment: As you've mentioned, the botbuilder-calling module used to handle calling events doesn't support LUIS, which is in the botbuilder class. LUIS is available with "message" type activities.

Comment: That being said, you mentioned you wanted to interact with the bot using voice. If you were willing to look into v4, there's a larger, more complex sample called Virtual Assistant that interacts with users via voice & text, which may be what you're looking for: https://github.com/Microsoft/AI/tree/master/solutions/Virtual-Assistant

Comment: Thanks Zeryth! On a high level this does seem like what I'm looking for. I'll go into this in more detail. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  Its possible!!!.

In bot project you can create LUISDialogue by providing LUIS keys, which actually communicate with LUIS.

For Skype BOT you will need to enable Skype endoint in BOT service in Azure.

Comment: Hi Sharad, Thanks for your response. But I am aware the we can integrate and use LUIS with the LUISAppId and LUISAPIKey and I'm already using this in my Chatbot. My question was specifically regarding whether we can integrate LUIS with a "Skype Calling Bot" (that can accept voice calls over Skype) as this seems to be a whole different matter.